# Pass a variable into a template

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Given this template:

```
<template id="minimal_layout_inherit" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
      <xpath expr="//head" position="inside">
             <link rel='stylesheet' href="my_module/static/src/css/mycss.css"/>
      </xpath>
</template>
```

How can I pass a variable named css_file from backend so the template can be rearranged to this:

```
<template id="minimal_layout_inherit" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
      <xpath expr="//head" position="inside">
             <link rel='stylesheet' t-att-href="css_file"/>
      </xpath>
</template>
```

I have tried KabyR's parser, adapted to my case. But css_file variable is not passed to inherited minimal_layout:
    class ParticularReport(models.AbstractModel):
        _name = 'report.my_module.report_saleorder'

```
    @api.model
    def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('my_module.report_saleorder')
        docs = self.env[report.model].browse(docids)
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': docids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': docs,
            'css_file': "/my_module/static/css/sale_report.css",
            'css_file2': "my_module/static/css/sale_report.css",
        }
        print '** DEBUG render_html docargs'
        print docargs
        for doc in docargs['docs']:
            print 'doc.id'
            print doc.id
        return report_obj.render('my_module.report_saleorder', docargs)
```

Given that I have in my custom module:

```
<template id="report_saleorder">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="my_module.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

being report.html_container the template who uses minimal_template (the one inherited where we want the variable).

But css_file is definitively not available in inherited template

```
    <template id="report_saleorder_css" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
        <xpath expr="html/head/*[position() = last()]" position="after">
            <link rel="stylesheet" t-attf-href="my_module/static/css/sale_report.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" t-att-href="css_file"/>
            <link t-att-href="'%s' % (css_file)" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link t-att-href="'%s' % (css_file2)" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <span>AAA</span><span><t t-esc="css_file" /></span><span>BBB</span>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

And you get

```
2017-06-23 00:03:09,376 5131 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2017 00:03:09] "GET /my_module/static/css/sale_report.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2017-06-23 00:03:09,397 5131 INFO demo_v10 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2017 00:03:09] "GET /None HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2017-06-23 00:03:09,963 5131 INFO demo_v10 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2017 00:03:09] "GET /None HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

As you can see hte first one (hardcoded) works, the second and third (use css_file and css_file2 variables) do not. Also nothing appears between AAA and BBB in the document. So css_file, is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.
**parser.py**

```
class ReportSaleOrderInherit(models.AbstractModel):

_name = 'report.sale.report_saleorder'
@api.model
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    report = self.env['report']._get_report_from_name('sale.report_saleorder')
    total = []
    model = report.model
    docs = self.env[model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': report.model,
        # 'data': data['form'],
        'docs': docs,
        'css_file':"/pos_general/static/src/css/report_css.css",
    }
    return self.env['report'].render('sale.report_saleorder', docargs)
```

**template.xml**

```
<template id="minimal_layout_inherit" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
  <xpath expr="//head" position="inside">
        <link t-att-href="'%s' % (css_file)" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: @usk70, if the answer resolved your issue. please make it as answer.

Comment: it does not work, I think the template is fine, but the parser is not.

Comment: just try to print `css_file` in your template. like <t t-esc='css_file'/>. Check out  it print or not?

Comment: With attf: 2017-06-19 13:30:10,553 11232 INFO demo_ps werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2017 13:30:10] "GET /css_file HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: just print it in document body. forget about t-attf.

Comment: Try like this: <link rel='stylesheet' t-attf-href="my_module/static/src/css/mycss.css"/>

Comment: <xpath expr="//head" position="inside"><span>XXXX</span><span><t t-esc="css_file"/></span><span>YYYY</span></xpath>  I can see the XXXX and the YYYY but nothing about the variable value

Comment: please post answer of my last comment.

Comment: <link rel='stylesheet' t-attf-href="my_module/static/src/css/mycss.css"/> this works, CSS is loaded and I can see the GET in the log. The issue is with the variable

Comment: It does not work, the problem is that the variable is not there.

Comment: The above code worked for for sale order report in my custom module. Please make sure, your custom parser is executing, please print something in it.

Comment: It does not work, did you test it in Odoo 10? I get an empty PDF (no pages).

Comment: Just add a `print` statement in your custom parser. And check whether it print on terminal or not!.

Comment: Yo got answer ?

Comment: Check my edited post to see results of the parser. I get an empty (no pages at all) PDF as result, and I guess the reason is that docs variable is not being populated in the custom parser. Other than that the css_file variable is properly populated (but obviously I need all other required fields for a regular display of sale_order documents).

Comment: In your 3rd print the model is empty. Please replace your module`my_module` with `sale' and try again.

Comment: I managed to find the issue with the parser, and now it works perfectly (see above code), but..., css_file is not available in the inherited template.

Comment: note that I am not invoking the standard sale.report_saleorder but a custom one in a custom module

Comment: I understood that. Check my parser class, i wrote in my custom module but called default sale order template. So that i got value for `model`. And the css file invoked from inherited template. Try in that way. Just try to call default report from your custom parser.

Comment: I changed as you say, now I get the default sale order template from my module, the parser is called, but the inherited minimal_layout template still has no access to css_file variable. I have also tried to make a parser for both report.minimal_layout and my inherited template for minimal_layout without success. They are not called, I start to think that report.minimal_layout is outside the regular flow of templates and no parser can be coded for it.